# Вызов функций в PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, psql

Написал функцию, в которой пару операторов IF выполняют некоторое действие со столбцами. Как мне вызывать эту функцию постоянно? пробовал через триггерную функцию, но тогда всё ломается и перестают появляться новые строки в таблицах без вызова каких-либо ошибок, поэтому триггерные функции не подходят точно. А когда вызываю обычную функцию через select func1(), то всё прекрасно работает. Вот как этот вызов функции зациклить? Мне нужно знать только как постоянно вызывать функции и всё.

Comment: Ну, например, через pgpro_scheduler.

Comment: pgpro_scheduler это фишка платной расширенной версии PostgreSQL, а как в бесплатной версии это сделать?

Comment: Начинается... ну дёргай свой запрос через крон и штатный клиент командной строки..